# How to only enable template function for specified types / disable for any other types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, function-templates-overloading

```
//my_utils.h
namespace A {
 namespace B {
  template <typename T, typename U>
  T encode( U value ) = delete;
  
  template <typename T, typename U>
  U decode( T value ) = delete;

  uint8_t encode( bool value );

  bool decode( uint8_t value );
  .
  .
  .
  //in this same .h file
  template <typename T>
  class X {
    public:
     void func() {
       uint8_t a = encode(bool_var);
     }
  };
 }
}

//myutils.cpp
namespace A {
 namespace B {
  
  uint8_t encode<uint8_t, bool>( bool value ) {
    //do something
  }

  bool decode<uint8_t, bool>( uint8_t value ) {
    //do something
  }

 }
}
```

It works this way but I was wondering... is this the right way? I was spending quite some time trying to make it work with template specialization but I just couldn't figure it out.For example it works with "const char *" but it's not what my intention was.

**My goal was to disable this function for any type other than those I specialized and disable implicit type conversion at the same time.**

Any toughts on this? Is there a better practice?

I'm using templates more and more and I really see some benefits there, but I still feel like I'm hopeless sometimes.

Comment: overloads are simpler than templates when the set of types is limited and small

Comment: What you are looking for has a name : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: @PepijnKramer - No, there's no immediate need for sfinae here. Not everything is a nail.

Comment: Herb Sutter has a good article about this http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm - Ever since C++'s inception, the rule of thumb was to prefer overloads to specializations.

Comment: If you choose correct order for template, you might have one deducible (Not sure if `T` and `U` should be related as pair though, (I mean can `encode<string, bool>` and `encode<std::uint32_t, bool>` coexist)).

Comment: I would start by implementing only the non templated functions I need. If, later on, I saw I could benefit from writing generic code, I would give it a go. Maybe by then I would be able to provide a clearer description of the issues I would be facing when writing that code.

Comment: Did you really mean to make `encode` and `decode` into template specializations in `myutils.cpp`? If so, they are missing `template<>`, but I assume you didn't mean to make them into specializations at all, right?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I know ;) But fair point nonetheless